# python numpy: how to identify column or row that has the smallest number of ones in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm looking to come up with a code that takes a 2-dimensional numpy array and returns the proportion of ones in each column or row divided by the column or row that has the smallest proportion of ones.
this is what i have so far:

```
if axis==1:
    m=np.array((a==1).sum(1)/ # something here )
else:
    m=np.array((a==1).sum(0)/ #something here )
```

Comment: Do you mean "and divide that _row or column_ by the row or column..."? What do you do with the sum of ones then?

Comment: i mean divide the sum of ones by the sum of ones in the row or column with the smallest proportion of ones

Comment: What do you mean by "proportion of ones", then? The number of ones? The fraction of ones with respect to the row/column length? Your question is unclear, and unless you rewrite it, you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: is that more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you work along the axis `axis` (which is 0 or 1). Start by finding the row/column counts of 1's:

```
counts = (arr==1).sum(axis=axis)
```

You can now find the index of the smallest count, select the appropriate count from the list of counts, and divide all other counts by it:

```
counts / counts[counts.argmin()]
```

Just remember that the smallest count can be 0.

Comment: how do i handle the case where i am dividing by 0?